# Resizing whole column

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to create table with resizable width of columns in pure JavaScript. See [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/tb1brnt3/). When I enlarge the size of let's say `td 1` and then I try to make it smaller by dragging the border of `td 3`, it is stuck and not possible to make it smaller unless you do it again with `td 1`. I guess the problem is it creates a div with certain size which is not possible to change while dragging with the border of `td 3`. Any ideas how can i change the div width from the other cell?

> JS:

```
(function () {
    var thElm;
    var startOffset;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("table td"),
      function (th) {
        th.style.position = 'relative';

        var grip = document.createElement('div');
        grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        grip.style.top = 0;
        grip.style.right = 0;
        grip.style.bottom = 0;
        grip.style.width = '5px';
        grip.style.position = 'absolute';
        grip.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
        grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            thElm = th;
            startOffset = th.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
        });

        th.appendChild(grip);
      });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      if (thElm) {
        thElm.style.width = startOffset + e.pageX + 'px';
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thElm = undefined;
    });
})();
```

> HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>th 1</th>
            <th>th 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td 1</td>
            <td>td 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td 3</td>
            <td>td 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can u please share the code you're written so far?

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd It's in the link above. [http://jsfiddle.net/tb1brnt3/](http://jsfiddle.net/tb1brnt3/)

Comment: ops, im sorry if i missed it

Comment: You need to put the relevant code in the question, so that if the JSFiddle ever gets deleted or stops working, your question will still make sense.

Comment: @ecg8 Got it, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is resizing the cell. Try resizing the header, instead of the cell.

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-header-id="col-1">th 1</th>
        <th data-header-id="col-2">th 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-column-id="col-1">td 1</td>
        <td data-column-id="col-2">td 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-column-id="col-1">td 3</td>
        <td data-column-id="col-2">td 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

var thElm;
var startOffset;
```

JS:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("table td"),
  function (th) {
    var columnId = th.attributes["data-column-id"].value;
    th.style.position = 'relative';

    var grip = document.createElement('div');
    grip.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    grip.style.top = 0;
    grip.style.right = 0;
    grip.style.bottom = 0;
    grip.style.width = '5px';
    grip.style.position = 'absolute';
    grip.style.cursor = 'col-resize';

    grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        thElm = document.querySelectorAll("[data-header-id='" + columnId + "']")[0];
      console.log(thElm);
        startOffset = thElm.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
    });

    th.appendChild(grip);
  });

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (thElm) {
        thElm.style.width = startOffset + e.pageX + 'px';
    }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thElm = undefined;
});
```

This is a fork of your fiddle, showing this updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/54n2rke9/12/

**Update: An alternate approach**

Here, the original HTML doesn't need to be changed.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("table td"),
  function (th) {
    th.style.position = 'relative';
    var cellIndex = th.cellIndex;
    ...
    grip.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
          thElm = document.querySelectorAll("th")[cellIndex];
        startOffset = thElm.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
    });

    th.appendChild(grip);
  });
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing the html code?

Comment: Yes, this will be possible. You can store a reference to the index of each cell in its row, using the cellIndex property. Then, query for all header elements in the mousedown event handler and select the one at the cell's index. This is a link to the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/54n2rke9/28/.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the alternate approach where the HTML doesn't need to be changed.